# How to insert both a variable and result of stored procedure into the same row in a temporary table?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table declared as

`DECLARE @tbl table
(
     a int,
     b int
)`

And I have a stored procedure `dbo.sp` that returns exactly one int and a variable `@a` that is assigned an int value. I want to insert both of these values into one row in the table.

I know that I can do

`INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    a
)
SELECT a = @a`

and

`INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    b
)
EXEC dbo.sp
    PARAMS`

but, my question is, how do I do both to get one row?

I should add that I have *very* limited experience with SQL and I am using SQL 2012.

Comment: Since your stored proc returns a single scalar, are you able to change the proc to a function?

Comment: I don't believe so. I have only been given permissions to edit this sp that calls the other one.

Answer (score 0):

With some more tinkering, I was able to get this to work with the following

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 ( b int )

INSERT INTO #T1
    EXEC dbo.sp
        PARAMS

INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    a,
    b
)
SELECT
    a = @a,
    b
FROM #T1
```

but if there is a better solution, I would love to hear it.